# Is there a way to configure custom RecordMessageConverter in spring-kafka?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I created a custom `RecordMessageConverter` which print in the `toMessage` and `fromMessage` (I create Bean as explained at https://www.confluent.io/blog/spring-for-apache-kafka-deep-dive-part-1-error-handling-message-conversion-transaction-support) but unfortunately it is not binded to the listener. Can I explicitly bind it or should I do something else to make it works?

```
public class MobileMessageConverter implements RecordMessageConverter {
    @Override
    public Message<?> toMessage(ConsumerRecord<?,?> record, Acknowledgment acknowledgment, Consumer<?, ?> consumer, Type payloadType) {
        System.out.println("Converting toMessage");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ProducerRecord<CustomKey, CustomValue> fromMessage(Message<?> message, String defaultTopic) {
        System.out.println("Converting fromMessage");
        return new ProducerRecord("UNKNOWN",new CustomValue());
    }
}


@RestController
public class CustomKafkaController {
    @Bean
    public RecordMessageConverter converter() {
        return new CustomMessageConverter();
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "UNKNOWN", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory", groupId = "1")
    public void listenAsObject(ConsumerRecord<CustomKey, CustomValue> cr) {
        System.out.println(cr.getValue().getCustomMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the exact issue? are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: no I didn't get exeptions, the listener get the message but it didn't print the strings from the `toMessage` and `fromMessage`

Comment: Probably your `@Bean converter()`  is not visible because you declare it inside a `@RestController`. Consider to have it in some `@Configuration` class instead.

Comment: You have implemented `RecordMessageConverter` which will convert payload to some type, so you need to complete the implementation instead of returning null. Then @KafkaListener method why are trying to consumer `ConsumerRecord`? your message converter will convert the payload to some type. What exactly you are trying to do here?

Comment: I’m trying to get some type and to convert to another type. Here I only print to see if it works.

Comment: Specific here I’m trying to convert from type to the same type and print the this operation happend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it!

1. I added the converter to the factory Bean (`kafkaListenerContainerFactory`) by its setter.
2. I changed the convert to implement `MessagingMessageConverter` insted of `RecordMessageConverter`  and I implemented the method `extractAndConvertValue`
3. **(If you want to change to other type)** remove the `listenAsObject` and replace it by the `ConsumerRecordtype` your convert to

For example:
If you want to change the custom value to String: 
create new converter:

```
public class CustomToStringMessageConverter extends MessagingMessageConverter {
    @Override
    protected String extractAndConvertValue(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record, Type type){
       return "EmptyString"
    }
}
```

change the listener to :

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "UNKNOWN", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerStringContainerFactory", groupId = "1")
public void listen2(String cr) {
    **DO SOMETHING WITH THE CONVERTED CR**
}
```

and the last thing is to get the converted Bean and set it in your factory by :

```
factory.setMessageConverter(new CustomToStringMessageConverter ());
```